# Servlet is not getting called

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

Inside my jsp page, I have this logic if a user performs a RemoveItem Action

On click of the Remove Item, based on the value selected, I need to fetch some information from Httpsession related to that.

So for this reason I was using AJAX for it as shown.

Maybe this picture can help in understanding the context.

[image]

```
<input type = "submit" name = "s" value = "Removeitem" onclick='checker();' />
```

This is my javascript function

```
function checker()
{
    var selObj = document.getElementById('selSeaShells');
    var optionselectedvalue = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value.split(':')[0];
    if(optionselectedvalue==''||optionselectedvalue==null)
        {
         alert('Select a Book');
         return false;
        }
     if (!text_form.quan.value)
         {
         alert('Enter Quantity');
         return false;
         }
     alert('ajax getting called');
     var xmlhttp;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
     else
       {// code for IE6, IE5    
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
       {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
         alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
         }
       }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","/ReturnQuantity",true);
     xmlhttp.send("selectedBook="+optionselectedvalue);
}
```

This is my web.xml

```
<web-app>
     <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ReturnQuantity</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ReturnQuantity</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ReturnQuantity</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ReturnQuantity</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ReturnQuantity</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

What might be causing the Problem here.

Comment: oh thanks a lot , i just saw console , i saw this now   http://localhost:8080/ReturnQuantity 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I've checked checked your JS in the meantime and that is fine, but checking JS error helped :) you should add the application context the the URL then...

Comment: I see of lot of white space (unnecessary lines) in the question. Please consider to edit it and make it more readable.